# Python logging with rsyslog

Tags: python, logging, python-2.6, rsyslog

I've inherited the following python file:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler

class Logger(object):

  # Return a logging instance used throughout the library
  def __init__(self):
    self.logger = logging.getLogger('my_daemon')

  # Log an info message
  def info(self, message, *args, **kwargs):
    self.__log(logging.INFO, message, *args, **kwargs)

  # Configure the logger to log to syslog
  def log_to_syslog(self):
    formatter = logging.Formatter('my_daemon: [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')

    handler = SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log', facility=SysLogHandler.LOG_DAEMON)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    self.logger.addHandler(handler)
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

I see that the init method looks for a logger called **my_daemon**, which I can't find anywhere on my system. Do I have to manually create the file and if so where should I put it?

Also, `log_to_syslog` appears to listen to socket `/dev/log`, and when I run `sudo lsof /dev/log` I get the following:

```
[vagrant@server]$ sudo lsof /dev/log
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
rsyslogd 989 root    0u  unix 0xffff880037a880c0      0t0 8099 /dev/log
```

When I look at `/etc/rsyslog.conf` I see the following:

```
# rsyslog v5 configuration file

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
```

So I'm a bit lost here. My init function seems to be instructing python to use a logfile called **my_daemon**, which I can't find anywhere, and /etc/rsyslog.conf seems to be telling the machine to use /var/log/messages, which does not contain any logs from my app.

Update: here's how I'm trying to log messages

```
import os
from logger import Logger

class Server(object):

  def __init__(self, options):
    self.logger = Logger()

  def write(self, data):
    self.logger.info('Received new data from controller, applying')
    print 'hello'
```

The write method from server.py does print 'hello' to the screen so I know we're getting close, it's just the logger that's not doing what I would expect

Comment: As the comments in `rsyslog.conf` specify, only messages with a priority of `info` or higher are logged. Does your program log such messages?

Comment: yes I've got `self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)`

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed that. However, my comment still stands. `logger.setLevel` sets the threshold of the logger, but attempting to log messages which are less severe is still possible (for example, via `logger.debug`), though they are ignored. Can you attach an example of actual logging attempt of a message that you expect to find in the log?

Comment: Sure, I added a bit more code, plus I inserted a method into Logger class.

Comment: Your init function is not instructing to save it on file, but giving a "name" to your log registries. You should check the file of the rsyslog (/var/log/messages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_daemon` is not a log file - it is just a developer-specified name indicating an "area" in an application. See [this](http://plumberjack.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/python-logging-101.html#loggers) information on what loggers are.

The `log_to_syslog` is not listening on a socket - the rsyslog daemon is doing that. Also, I don't see where `log_to_syslog` is called - is it? If it isn't called, that would explain why no messages are being seen in the syslog.

Comment: Thanks, I got this figured out now, thanks for the link