# How to configure rsyslog to use the centralized log with Python

Tags: python, logging, rsyslog

The rsyslog with elk runs well in a docker of localhost.

I could see the logs in Kibana with commands below:

```
logger -n localhost 'log message from test99'
logger -n localhost 'log message from test99'
logger -n 10.211.55.12 'log message from test99'
logger -n 10.211.55.12 'log message from test99234234'
```

The questions here, I want to use rsyslog with my Python application. The demo code shows below with the same configuration of rsyslog.

But I couldn't get anything from the Python application. So what's wrong with my configuration or code?

10.211.55.12 is the IP address of my localhost

#### log_test.py

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

logger = logging.getLogger('myLogger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Add handler to the logger
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler('/dev/log')

# Add formatter to the handler
formatter = logging.Formatter('Python: { "loggerName":"%(name)s", "asciTime":"%(asctime)s", "pathName":"%(pathname)s", "logRecordCreationTime":"%(created)f", "functionName":"%(funcName)s", "levelNo":"%(levelno)s", "lineNo":"%(lineno)d", "time":"%(msecs)d", "levelName":"%(levelname)s", "message":"%(message)s"}')

handler.formatter = formatter
logger.addHandler(handler)
for _ in range(100):
    logger.info("Test Message")
```

#### rsyslog.conf

```
 47 $DirCreateMode 0755
 48 $Umask 0022
 49 $PrivDropToUser syslog
 50 $PrivDropToGroup syslog
 51
 52 #
 53 # Where to place spool and state files
 54 #
 55 $WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog
 56
 57 #
 58 # Include all configuration files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
 59 #
 60 $IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
 61 *.* 10.211.55.12:514
 62
 63
 64 # Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
 65
 66 # Don't log private authentication messages!
 67
 68 *.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none      /var/log/messages
 69
 70 # The authpriv file has restricted access.
 71
 72 authpriv.*                                    /var/log/secure
 73
 74 # Log all the mail messages in one place.
 75
 76 mail.*                                        /var/log/maillog
 77
 78 # Log cron stuff
 79
 80 cron.*                                        /var/log/cron
 81
 82 # Everybody gets emergency messages
 83
 84 *.emerg                                       *
 85
 86 # Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
 87
 88 uucp,news.crit                                /var/log/spooler
 89
 90 # Save boot messages also to boot.log
 91
 92 local7.*                                      /var/log/boot.log
```

Comment: Could you try the with default parameters, i.e. `SysLogHandler()` without `/dev/log`?

Comment: @VPfB socket.error happened. logging.handlers.SysLogHandler('')

Comment: Please omit the quotes, just `SysLogHandler()`.

Comment: @VPfB Thanks. Seems working... confusing about why would this happen? There aren't any tutorials mentioned it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your setup correctly, but to send log messages outside of the local system, you need a network connection. UDP pakcets sent to logserver's port 514 are traditionally used for that task. (TCP is now supported as well and it has advantages over UDP). The `SysLogHandler` is doing UDP by default.

Comment: @VPfB Yes, you are right.  https://www.loggly.com/docs/python-syslog/  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807043/python-logging-with-rsyslog. Before posting this question, I Googled a lot, and found these two tutorials. I thought I should set SysLogHandler() with "/dev/log". It seemed that it would send logs to this file , then rsyslog will retransmit it to the log server. That's the confusing point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@VPfB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817152/how-to-configure-rsyslog-to-use-the-centralized-log-with-python?noredirect=1#comment74673295_43817152)'s comment is right. Change logging.handlers.SysLogHandler('/dev/log') to logging.handlers.SysLogHandler() will work for my case. Thanks @VPfB!